# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Why is the DOM tries to load before 'created'?

Tags: vue.js

In my application, I have this in my template:

```
<template>
    <div>{{ report.imageId.length }}</div>
</template>
```

In my script:

```
created() {
    this.loadReport();
},

methods: {
    async loadReport() {
        this.report = await reportSvc.getReport(this.$route.params.id);
    },
}
```

When I load the page, I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" in the DevTool. The HTML does print the correct numbers though. Why does the error comes out though?

I assume the error is because the DOM tries to read from the 'report' variable, but since loadReport() is not finished yet, that is why it errors out. But I thought the 'created' comes first before the DOM is loaded and rendered?

This question isn't how to make the error goes away, I want to know why the DOM gets loaded before the 'created'.

Comment: change `report.imageId.length` to `(report!==undefined && report!==null) ? report.imageId.length : 0 `

Comment: I know :) I'm just curious why the error comes out, since the DOM shouldn't be loaded yet (as per my understanding)

Comment: Maybe it could be in cache?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need this:

```
async beforeMount() {
    await this.loadReport();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In `created` hook you are able to access reactive data and events that are active but templates and Virtual DOM have not yet been mounted or rendered.

if you call for an API however it doesn't wait for the result and then move on to the next life cycle hook, this is how it goes:

1. created hook starts and you have access to reactive data and events
2. you call the API
3. API is asynchronous so the code goes on you reach `beforeMount` and `mounted` hook but the data isn't updated yet since there's no response yet, DOM renders and you get the error

one way to get pass the error is to use a condition like this in your template:

```
{{ report.imageId ? report.imageId.length : '' }}
```

this way your user get to see the app and doesn't have to wait for the response to come if it's taking a long time and by the time the response comes, template gets updated

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `v-if` check to make sure the data exists: `<div v-if="report">...`.

The reason is that you're loading data asynchronously, so it won't exist when the component is created.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: created -> loadReport() starts -> DOM gets loaded -> error comes out -> loadReport() finished?